# How to remove unrecognized character via MySQL query or PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have uploaded **CSV via CLI command** and in the `CSV` have used bullets with description column.

When it imported in `MySQL` its showing like boxes for reference we have also attached screenshot. i want to replace with `<li>` tag or any other character. But neither i am able to select and replace character in `MYSQL nor vi PHP`.

I have already try `update table name set field = replace(filed,"spacial","")` but character not recognized in `MySQL` query.[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual content  from the database around the text you want to change. It may help identify what can be done to fix it.

Comment: 6-Panel 3 1/2" Structured Crown Two Tone
        Cotton Twill
        Snap Closure
        One Size Fits Most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys for solutions but i got the solution to replace character bullet was not visible in database but i have tried and got luck.  it was replaced luckily.

MYSQL update script for Magento 1 product short description and description update query. you can also run with your tables via replace table name and fields.

UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` SET value = REPLACE(value,'•        ','') WHERE entity_id = 141047 and attribute_id in (73,74)

Answer (score 0):

We can change on front-end with help of javascript. So, share your website single page link or HTML from top (id or class).

Comment: This is my website link: http://synapse.asia/10492_designcaps/catalog/product/view/id/141073 where i need to replace this character.